# Config files access rights blocking saving changes?

Tags: gnome, permissions, configuration, system-settings

I have installed Ubuntu 16.10 + Gnome Flashback. Previously I had Ubuntu 14.04 which I managed to break completely by upgrade halted in the middle.

I've backed up all files from $HOME and /etc and few other, using bootable Ubuntu DVD. After installation, I've copied all files from former $HOME to the new one. It had owner/group root/root. I've done `chown -R ondra ~/.*` and `chgrp -R ondra ~/.*`.

However, I still observe quite weird behavior on different levels. Many settings don't get saved. For instance, keyboard switching shortcut, screens layout, Konsole profile. Sometimes, wakeup doesn't work, computer stays blank and I have to shut down by holding power off; not sure if that's related.

I started to suspect that I have the access rights wrong. Maybe somewhere the apps use other user to store the config?

Should the config files have 777 or 555 or 550 or 750 or...?

Are the aforementioned settings stored also in `/etc/*`?

How can I check where the apps attempt to write but fail because of lack of write access?

Comment: Just as a side note, `.*` is a dangerous glob, as it includes the parent directory `..`

Comment: Hm, /home is now owned by `ondra/ondra`. I guess that should be owned by `root/root`?

Comment: yes, it should be owned by `root root`

Comment: Related: For the next reinstalation: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43605/how-do-i-copy-a-folder-keeping-owners-and-permissions-intact

Comment: What should I use not to match `..`?

Comment: good question! I just [asked it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/829796/how-should-i-glob-for-all-hidden-files)

Comment: did you fix this?