# How should I glob for all hidden files?

Tags: command-line, bash, files, wildcards

I want to carry out some action (say `chown`) on all the hidden files in a directory.

I know that this `.*` is **not** a good idea because it will also find the current `.` and parent `..` directories (I know that `rm` will fail to operate on `.` and `..` but other commands, including `chown` and `chmod`, will happily take effect)

But all my hidden files have different names!

How should I glob for all hidden files while excluding `.` and `..` ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the following `extglob` pattern:

```
.@(!(.|))
```

- `.` matches a literal `.` at first
- `@()` is a `extglob` pattern, will match one of the patterns inside, as we have only one pattern inside it, it will pick that
- `!(.|)` is another `extglob` pattern (nested), which matches any file with no or one `.`; As we have matched `.` at start already, this whole pattern will match all files starting with `.` except `.` and `..`.

`extglob` is enabled on interactive sessions of `bash` by default in Ubuntu. If not, enable it first:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo .@(!(.|))
.bar .foo .spam
```

Comment: This is clearly an awesome thing I need to learn about! Thank you for teaching

Comment: @Zanna Glad i could help :)

Comment: What is the purpose of the `@()`? Simple `.!(.|)` seems to work identically.

Comment: I know that this is old, but I have the same question as @KyleStrand. In my tests, `!(.|)` works the same. Is there any purpose behind `@()` in this context?

Comment: Is the bang character a negation? It is not mentioned, and reading your explanation, I get the impression, that the pattern matches dot and doubledot, but you clearly describe files which match a starting dot, except just those two.

Comment: @userunknown, right, `!()` means to not match any of the pipe-separated alternatives inside of it, so basically this is saying: match a dot, but do not let the second character match a dot or an empty string. As pointed out above, the `@()` which means to pick only one of the pipe-separated alternatives, does not have a purpose since there are no alternatives. My golden source for glob information is this primer from node-glob (See https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer) which is equivalent to enabling dotglob in the shell

Answer (score 33):

In Bash, set the `GLOBIGNORE` variable as follows:

```bash
GLOBIGNORE=".:.."
```

to hide the `.` and `..` directories. This also sets the `dotglob` option so that the glob `*` character now matches both *hidden* and *non-hidden* files. Setting the `GLOBIGNORE` variable as shown above only affects the current terminal session and top-level processes unless you export it and and add it to your `~/.bashrc` file as `export GLOBIGNORE=".:.."`.

You can also do:

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

Source: [Gilles' answer here :)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6397/114401)

Comment: IMO this is better than the accepted answer. Easier to remember, infinitely more intuitive, and able to be stuffed into `.bashrc` to make it permanent if one so wishes (I know I almost never want `*` to mean "non-dotfiles only").

Answer (score 10):

You can use a `find` command here. For example something like

```
find -type f -name ".*" -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

This will find hidden files and change permissions

---

Edit to include the comment by @gerrit:

```
find -type f -maxdepth 1 -name ".*" -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

This will limit the search top the current directory instead of searching recursively.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone need an alternative that doesn't require environment variables or shell options enabled like `dotglob` or `extglob`you can use the following:

`.[!.]*`

it works because it matches at least two characters, the second of which must not be a dot (`.`)

I came to this question because I was looking for a way to match dotfiles and non-dotfiles, for which you could use:

`{.[!.]*,*}`

which matches either of the two options.

I needed a glob that didn't require environment variables nor shell options; and the reason is that I needed a glob that worked in VSCode's `findFiles` API, which supports globs (See https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#3906), but doesn't offer room for shell options nor `dotglob` or `extglob` equivalents. It is nice that these tools decided to use the *NIX way for doing globs.